# Extracting attribute from DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hash

I need to return a string that is nested within a DOM element. The string *looks like* a value that is stored to a key or attribute called "selector"

I've been using the console to try to get down to that string.

My HTML = [image]

this JavaScript/JQuery:

```
console.log($(this.nextSibling.data));
```

logs to the console 
[image: console output]

I have tried:

```
console.log($(this.nextSibling.data.selector));
console.log($(this.nextSibling.data[selector]));
console.log($(this.nextSibling.data(selector)));
```

etc. without much luck. Since I'm not sure I even know what this data structure is, I don't know how to return " gi" (in this example) from the key-like-thing "selector:"

How can I get that string?

Comment: Have you attempted `console.log($(this.nextSibling.data['selector']))` ?

Comment: What does the element in question look like? I'm not aware of any `data` property on [nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: It could be referring to a class, since selectors are either elements, ids, or classes (in CSS, anyways)

Comment: `$(this.nextSibling.data)` makes no sense

Comment: I would guess `$(this.nextSibling).data("selector")`

Comment: @Phil thanks, but this returns undefined

Comment: Show some sample markup, otherwise everyone is just guessing.

Comment: And @richard kho, thanks, but your formulation returns an empty array.

Comment: I will add markup, one moment.

Comment: So you added the HTML And how do you get `this` in the JavaScript? Still unclear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do here? What piece of data from which element are you trying to retrieve? What triggers your code to run?

Comment: Which string do you need returned from which DOM element?

Comment: @Phil, I want to find the string connected to "selector:" because it matches a string I've stored to chrome.storage. If I can find those strings relative to 'this', I have a flexible way to refer to the strings I want to delete from my storage. In the image I shared, I would want to extract the string " gi"

Comment: What is `this` though? You can't just have plain `this`, you need to get to it somehow.

Comment: @richard shi, `this` refers to the div that is removed on click of the checkbox.

Comment: Attribute values are retrieved with `elem.getAttribute("propName")`.  I can find no attribute named "selector" in the HTML you show so it is hard to advise you in any productive manner.  Basically, we can't tell what you're trying to do with the HTML you show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `this.nextSibling.data` (without transforming it into a jQuery-object)

When `this.nextSibling` is a textNode(or commentNode) it's `data`-property returns the textContent (characterData) of this node.

Comment: [`node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) is usually the way text is retrieved from a text node and `elem.textContent` from an element.  `.textContent` retrieves the concatenation of all text nodes inside the element.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive response, @Dr.Molle.

Comment: @coolalligator15—yeah, sorry, that will return the textContent of the wrong node (deleted).

Comment: @jfriend00— [*nodeValue*](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-nodevalue) is on every node, but the [*data*](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-cd-data) attribute is for nodes that contain character data. Either will work, the only difference is that the former will return *null* for element nodes and the latter *undefined*. BTW, there is also a [*wholeText*](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-text-wholetext) property that is a concatenation of all contiguous text nodes.